# Multiple WooCommerce site reports on one page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

We are company that owns multiple web stores that are made on Wordpress -> WooCommerce platform. Now we would like to have reports of all pages together on one place. That we will see graphs for each site.

Do you know any plugins that will allow something like that? We would like to have reports from all pages together, that we will know better with marketing and so one.

Thanks for help,
Matic

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, a plugin, a software library, a tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic on Stack Overflow…

Answer (score 0):

Mention plugin will help you to monitor vendor wise sales report https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/product-vendors/